# create a root user - mission failed

Tags: linux, centos, root

**Centos 6.8**
Attempt to create a new **root** user

```
adduser root_2
passwd root_2
Changing password for user root_2.
New password: 
Retype new password: 
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
```

run **visudo**, locate the line with **root**, clone the line and make it for **root_2**

```
visudo

## Allow root to run any commands anywhere
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
root_2    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

save and quit

```
 :wq
```

switch to user **root_2**  and test to see if it behaves like **root** account

```
su root_2

reboot
reboot: Need to be root
```

let's also try this stuff that I find on the web.

as **root**

```
usermod -aG wheel root_2
su root_2
reboot
reboot: Need to be root
```

again.. no success..

mission failed.

What Am I Missing ?

Comment: See this Q&A over at ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/390988/multiple-linux-sysadmins-working-as-root

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can only be one `root` user: the user with user id 0. From the point of the system, user accounts are small integer numbers. The alphanumeric names are just a convenience for the operator. The new user `root_2` does not have user id 0, so it is not `root` by definition.

By editing the `sudoers` file you have given `root_2` the right to run any command anywhere using `sudo`. You did not make it equivalent to `root`, because only user id 0 is `root`.